# How do I check if a page exists in a Restful API (namely PokeAPI)?

Tags: php

Very new to PHP here. I am playing around with PokeAPI and want to check if a data entry exists. On the API itself, a link to a page with an invalid number (e.g. https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6666666/) gives this:

```
{"detail":"Not found."}
```

I want a message to be displayed on my app if the entry is empty/invalid. Here is the code I have written (I have a form on another page which provides the integer 'dexno'):

```
if (!empty($_POST["dexno"])) {
      $dexno = $_POST["dexno"];
      $data = file_get_contents($base.$dexno);
      if ($data != "") {
        $pokemon = json_decode($data);
        $img = $pokemon->sprites->front_default;
        $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($img));
        echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$imageData.'">';
      }
      else{
        die("No Pokemon found.");
      }
    }
```

When I run it in my browser I encounter the following message:

> ( ! ) Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6666666): failed to
>   open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND in
>   C:\wamp64\www\pokemon\process.php on line 24

After this is shown, the "No Pokemon found." message is displayed correctly. Any ideas as to what might be wrong? I may have missed out some details so feel free to ask questions :)

Comment: Nothing is wrong. Your program works as you expect it. What is your question really?

Comment: My question is how to get rid of the warning displayed  as a result of the file_get_contents method :)

Comment: `@file_get_contents()` http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: Are you talking about something like `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);` ?